# Can I hide aliased email addresses in a Postfix reject message?

Tags: postfix

`alias@domain.com` is an alias for `secret@domain.com`. When Postfix rejects a message, it replies with the expanded alias:

```
<secret@domain.com>: host smtp.domain.com[xx.xx.xx.xx] said: 550
    5.7.23 <secret@domain.com>: Recipient address rejected: Message
    rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Please see
    http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=mfrom;id=test@email.com;ip=xx.xx.xx.xx;r=domain.com
    (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

I would like to either remove `<secret@domain.com>` or show `<alias@domain.com>` in the reject message.

How can this be done?

Comment: What's your current configuration?